Declare Typescript-Type both implicit and explicit
The following code just perfectly generates me a type that only allows existing hobbies:
const personWithHobby = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 30,
        hobby: "Football"
    },
    {
        name: "Doe",
        age: 24,
        hobby: "Soccer"
    }
] as const;

type Hobby = typeof personWithHobby[number]['hobby'];
let hobby: Hobby = 'Football';
//Does not work:
hobby = 'Tennis';

Now I need this type to be of the following type, too:
type Person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    doSomething: (v: string) => string;
};

My first attempt does not work since TS wants me to remove hobby:
const personWithHobby: Person[] = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 30,
        doSomething: v => v.length.toString(),
        //ts(2353) only known properties
        hobby: "Football"
    }
] as const;

Removing the type does work, but now the parameter type of doSomething can't be resolved automatically:
const personWithHobby = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 30,
        //ts(7006) implicit any type
        doSomething: v => v.length.toString(),
        hobby: "Football"
    }
] as const;

I know I could allow implicit any, but I want the type to be known. Is it somehow possible to achieve both? Implicitly creating a new type based on the current one? So I can (again implicitly) have a type Hobby?
Edit: @Teneff found an awesome solution! But can this be achieved, too?
type FormType = unknown;

type Question = {
  question: string,
  getNextQuestion?: (value: FormType) => Question | null
};

const Questions = [
  {
    id: 'q1',
    question: 'Q1?',
    //Breaks the code
    //getNextQuestion: v => QuestionsMap.q1
  },
  {
    id: 'q2',
    question: 'Q2?',
  }
] as const satisfies (Question & Record<'id', string>)[];

type QuestionIds = typeof Questions[number]['id'];
const QuestionsMap = Object.fromEntries(Questions.map(q => [q.id , q])) as unknown as { [key in QuestionIds]: Question };

//Works perfectly!
const q1 = QuestionsMap.q1;

As soon as I set a getNextQuestion the code breaks (probably because of self-referencing). Is this somehow possible?

You can define it like this
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  doSomething?: (v: string) => string;
};

const personWithHobby = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 30,
    hobby: "Football"
  },
  {
    name: "Doe",
    age: 24,
    hobby: "Soccer"
  }
] as const satisfies (Person & Record<'hobby', string>)[];

type Hobby = typeof personWithHobby[number]['hobby']
//   ^? type Hobby = "Football" | "Soccer"

playground
Edit (update):
instead of self referencing you can write an assertion function applying the doSomething on a later stage
function peopleWithHobbiesDoingSomething(people: Person[]): asserts people is Array<Required<Person>> {
  (personWithHobby as Person[]).forEach((person): asserts person is Required<Person> => {
    person.doSomething = otherPeopleWithHobbyLikeMine.bind(person)
  })
}

playground
I think the approach would really depend on the implementation required

Sure! satisfies for the rescue! Your a true TS-magican! I've adopted my question a bit, your answer is awesome anyway! But is maybe a solution possible for this "self-ref-problem"?

Sorry, I unnecessarily reduced my use-case. Now I've changed my Edit again to my real one, guess it's clearer now. Sorry - and thank you so much for your effort!
